# Vanilla JS (no jQuery) - How to toggle more than one class at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am dealing with a legacy system and I can't rewrite the whole css.

So I find myself in need to toggle 2 classes on the same element when another one is clicked (imagine clicking on a button to hide/show a modal).

The following is the code for the modal.
Where the modal window is by default `.hidden` (without the class "visible") and on click it is `.visible` (without the class "hidden").

```js
function openModal(modalID) {
  document.getElementById(modalID)
    .classList.toggle('hidden');

  document.getElementById(modalID)
    .classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

```html
I agree to accept the
<a href="#" 
   onclick="openModal('tandcmodal')">
       terms and conditions
</a>
of this website.



<div id="tandcmodal"
     class="hidden">
    Content of the modal
</div>
```

So, I believe there must be a way to toggle more than one class at once with `.toggle()`.
Or isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `.toggle` [accepts only one argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle): the one class name you wish to toggle. To be DRY, you'll have to iterate over an array of class names, or save the classList in a variable and call `.toggle` twice:

```js
function openModal(modalID) {
  const { classList } = document.getElementById(modalID);
  classList.toggle('hidden');
  classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
I agree to accept the
<a href="#" onclick="openModal('tandcmodal')">
       terms and conditions
</a> of this website.



<div id="tandcmodal" class="hidden">
  Content of the modal
</div>
```

But note that *usually* there's no need for both a `hidden` and a `visible` class. Often you can have *just* a `hidden` class, and add it / remove it, letting the default display style take effect when `hidden` is not active:

```js
function openModal(modalID) {
  document.getElementById(modalID).classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
I agree to accept the
<a href="#" onclick="openModal('tandcmodal')">
       terms and conditions
</a> of this website.



<div id="tandcmodal" class="hidden">
  Content of the modal
</div>
```

Also note that inline attribute handlers behave [*very*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) strangely, have escaping problems, and are generally considered to be quite poor practice - they should probably be avoided in almost all cases. Consider adding the event listener using Javascript instead:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => openModal('tandcmodal'));
function openModal(modalID) {
  document.getElementById(modalID).classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
I agree to accept the
<a href="#">
       terms and conditions
</a> of this website.



<div id="tandcmodal" class="hidden">
  Content of the modal
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but unfortunately this is not the case :(